# Pleasure of God: virtuous life

Tags: vocabulary

I have read a phrase in a religious writing 'pleasure of God'. I had a kind of feeling that 'pleasure' doesn't fit best here. The writer meant to say:

to please God

He used a noun form. His writing was about good deeds, virtues that humans do to please God. His sentence was:

Can he make atonement by giving charity for the pleasure of God?

I think it should be:

Can he make atonement by giving charity to please God.

Am I right?

Do natives use this phrase 'pleasure of God'? Do you say, [I am worshiping for the pleasure of God.]?

Actually the word 'pleasure' seems to give kind of different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

We can say that we perform an act using a noun to indicate the purpose of the act.

An act carried out to please God, or anyone else, is done for the pleasure of that person. Likewise, we can say, for example, that a teacher makes a demonstration, delivers a lecture, etc, for the instruction of his or her pupils.

Comment: So 'pleasure of God' is ok to use?

Comment: Or 'that person' means 'the doer'?

Comment: I've never come across the expression _for the pleasure of God_. Though what Michael says is perfectly true, to use the word _pleasure_ in this context feels odd because it can be associated with sensual enjoyment (though it doesn't have to be, of course). Unless the writer was deliberately using a surprising form of expression, it would be better to say _to please God_.

Comment: It's here and there in the Bible, e.g. God takes pleasure in his creation, is pleased by virtuous acts, etc. More common in later-than-KJV versions.

Comment: " God takes pleasure in his creation" means: He is/gets pleased with His creation. ???